# Website isn't viewed properly on Android Opera Mini browser

Tags: android, css, responsive-design, media-queries, opera-mini

My website [www.krishisansar.com](http://www.krishisansar.com) isn't properly viewed only in **Android Opera Mini browser**, another browsers display it properly.

It is a responsive website, when I resize screen using desktop's Opera, all is well. According to my CSS code, layout matches in perfectly. But when I open website from Android Opera Mini, GIF images don't show, words are stretched unnecessarily, layout is distorted. What is problem?

As others have advised, I changed CSS media queries form media only `screen` to media `all`, but nothing changed. What's wrong? Is it my coding fault or Opera Mini bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opera mini doesn't support gif files.

Comment: oh ! Thanks for answering. And can you give idea regarding layout ? My website uses unicode, there is no english font in website. I see many other websites which uses unicode have same problem regarding word spacing. I think opera mini automatically increases actual unicode word space and this affects layout. Is it there any idea ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the answer to that part of the question.

Comment: Why is Opera Mini so popular then? It can't even display gifs and it doesn't even support border-radius http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius - this makes it annoying to develop proper websites

Comment: Opera Mini provides server side compression (requests are tunneled through Opera's servers), which makes browsing faster and saves mobile users a lot of bandwidth. Other browsers have started implementing this as well, but Opera is leading. I think many users (that is, about 8% of the complete mobile market share) prefer a fast, lightweight browser over support for animated gifs and rounded corners. That's my guess. I don't use it myself, so I can't tell you if it really is better.